# Как управлять камерой Onvif?

Tags: c++, c, onvif

*Прошу сразу не кидаться тапками ибо не знаю, подходит ли данный вопрос по тематике этого сайта. Если вопрос не подходит. Я удалю его.*

Хотелось бы понять, как управлять камерой Onvif. Как работает сервер Onvif и какие команды он посылает камере. Есть ли где посмотреть исходники на C или C++?

Comment: Способ 1. Найти специфкации и прочитать. Способ 2. Задампить протокол общения с работающим софтом и отреверсинжинирить. Способ 3. Твой новый способ!

Comment: Вы бы хоть ссылки привели о том, что это.

Comment: И самое главное - что значит _управлять_? Управлять аудио/видео потоком и менять его параметры? Или менять внутренние состояния камеры (экспозиция, положение кадра, приближение/удаление, баланс белого и т.д.)

Comment: @user1056837 все, что вы описали.. под этим я и подразумеваю управлять. Не могу найти не одной спецификации или документации, которая бы хоть немного дала понять, как управлять этими камерами. Точнее, что отправляет сервер Onvif на свои камеры - какие команды

Comment: @Insider ну про отсутствие документации или специфкации вы как-то преувеличиваете. http://www.onvif.org/Documents/Specifications.aspx Затем про управление. В основе Onvif лежит RTSP, следовательно управление потоком можно делать в соответствии с этим протоколом. Технические характеристиики обычно решаются другими средствами. В общем, слишком много неизвестных. Определитесь, что вы хотите делать. Поставьте задачу.

Comment: @user1056837 надо почитать сперва спецификации )